# AWS Multi-account deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codestar

I have all my microservices hosted in codestar, with their cloudformation scripts. Everything working well.

I want to create a new Organizational Unit and deploy in a new account. 
What's the best way of doing this?

I've read that codestar does not support this functionality but I need to find a way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do cross account deployments by using Codepipeline together with Codeploy for deploy action. This is a good place to start https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html.

I recently realized a cross account deployments to ECS following the steps described in the doc.

Comment: I was reading the same page you sent. I think that's the best way to go. To have a "production" branch or a release branch and execute codepipeline in other accounts based on changes on that specific branch.

Comment: I'm looking that this doesn't scale if my plan is to have one AWS Account per customer. 
With this I need to create a new pipeline per customer, or having multiple deploys inside one pipeline

Comment: In that case you could try Stacksets in Cloudformation to create the pipeline as a part of the baseline while setting up customer accounts.

Comment: Is it possibleto use stackset with codestar? the cloudformation templates generated by codestar are not supported by stackset (transform is not supported)