# AWS CDK Multi Account Deploy Credentials In Trusted Account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

When [cdk bootstrapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html) AWS account `A` I am utilizing the `--trust` flag for account `B`:

```
CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT=A cdk boostrap --trust B ...
```

This should allow B to deploy into the A environment.

However, when a code pipeline job (with no `~/.aws` directory and no environment variable credentials) in B is running `cdk deploy` against A it errors out with

```
failed: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account A, but the current credentials are for B
```

The execution role for the code pipeline action in account B has admin access.

**How is a process in the trusted account credentialed to deploy to the boostrapped account?**

There is a [similarly titled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170184/aws-multi-account-deployment) which is for a separate topic.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Your explanation should be about right. Can you post your cdk pipeline code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the target `A` account is bootstrapped there is an `IAM Role` created in a A with a name like `"cdk-...deploy-role..."`.  By passing the `--trust B` flag when bootstrapping, a Trust Relationship is created in that deploy IAM Role that allows `B` account to assume the role.

In the B code pipeline you need to first [assume the A deploy role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63241009/aws-sts-assume-role-in-one-command):

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn <deploy_role_from_A_arn>
```

Then use the supplied credentials when invoking the `cdk deploy` command in code pipeline.